# Connecting to the internet with flash iOS development

Tags: iphone, flash, ios, ipod

I was reading that certain API's are not available when making iPhone apps with flash, such as accessing the camera. Is it possible to still get information from the web and display it in the app using the flash method? The overall plan is to have it pull data from an SQL database using XML, and I was just wondering if that was possible still with flash. Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: Learn objective C, flash development will only hinder you on the iOS platform.

Comment: I know this question is slightly older but still important. @logancautrell Why does Flash development hinder someone with iOS systems? Why develop a seperate app for the web, the iphone and the android? With Flash write once and distribute to all 3.

Comment: I *love* flash and spend nearly all my time developing in it, but the cross compiler is terrible. Performance is abysmal for anything that needs to update the screen in any regular fashion, I would really consider going native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard the same thing about it not being able to connect to the internet, among many other restraints, when developing apps through Flash. It held me back for the first 3 months after Apples 'accept' of the platform.

But now after I've had some time to test things out on my own, I found out that the following is possible (so far):

- Getting xml and pictures from the web (so why not SQL)
- saving cookies
- Saving pictures to the cameraroll.
- getting geoLocation data (didn't get the google maps api to work YET tho)

And these are only the features i have tried so far (in development-phase, not submittet to Apple)

I'm surprised that no one else has answered your question by now.
Hope this helps gets you spirit up for developing apps with flash :)